# Firefox and Angular: Textarea placeholder doesn't appear until first focus

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angularjs-scope

I have a super-simple Angular app:

```
<div ng-app>
  <ul>
    <li ng_if='true'>
      <textarea placeholder='Hello'></textarea>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

That's it. No JS / CSS.

In FF (34.0 on OSX), the placeholder in the Textarea will not show up until the textarea is focused.

What I've discovered thus far:

- It's only on textarea. Text inputs are fine.
- It's only when it's within a child $scope. If the `ng-if` wasn't there, the issue would disappear.

Play around with it [here](http://codepen.io/mendel/pen/WbQLYq).

I'm out of ideas. Any help would be super appreciated! :)

Comment: I can confirm this on FF 33.1 on Windows 7.  It does not occur on Chrome.  Perhaps a bug report to Mozilla is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Gecko, which has been resolved: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1088158

The fix should be shipped in stable in a few months, but in the meantime, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is correct. Fix is in nightly, as answered by [@caitp](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10325#issuecomment-65648757)

Answer (score 0):

This (ugly) work-around seems to work.

```
<div ng-app>
  <ul>
    <li ng_if='true'>
      <textarea placeholder='Hello'>{{''}}</textarea>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```