# Input field bug on IOS - text turns white

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I am working on a website and stumbled upon this bug

In the moment I start typing in the input field the first letter is with normal color but all the others are becoming white so you cannot see what you are typing. It is the same for Chrome and Safari

If I scroll the page up or down it is getting fixed.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Anyone any idea ?

UPDATE:
I found the reason, I use  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
If I remove it the inputs are working find but I need the scroll: touch because otherwise the site scrolls really weirdly and stucks

Comment: Is there any CSS managing an input disabled / onfocusout / ... state?

Comment: Try this: `-webkit-text-fill-color:#000;`

Comment: Try specifying color for the input, input[type=text] {
    color:#000;
}

Comment: I just found what is the reason, I use  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
If I remove it the inputs are working find but I need the scroll: touch because otherwise the site scrolls really weirdly and stucks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS textarea text hidden when using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730103/ios-textarea-text-hidden-when-using-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue with a textarea. What helped me to solve it is to add a:

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

on the textarea. Give it a shot.

Comment: This fixed it for me, but the issue only happens on certain inputs in the app. I can't figure out what is protecting all the others inputs, so there must be another solution. Also, using `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px)` works, since the issue is webkit specific.